# Unity3D: How to move object using device microphone as input?

Tags: javascript, android, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm trying to create a game that responds to certain voice pitch via device microphone. But unity does not support something like this. However, they can record your voice using device [microphone](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Microphone.html).

```
var aud = GetComponent.<AudioSource>();
aud.clip = Microphone.Start("Built-in Microphone", true, 10, 44100);
```

is it possible to use `aud.pitch` as input to move a rigidbody without it recording but just getting the input realtime, say

```
ball.velocity.y = jumpHeight * aud.pitch; // move up
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe that pitch is just a default value that you can modify to alter an audio source. I doubt it actually detects a pitch value every frame a sound is played. You can however use .NET libraries such as [Vocalyz](http://github.com/Skinz3/Vocalyz)